# Iterating through a dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to write a test for a function, and create a fake dictionary to use in the test - however, I cannot work out what the format of the dictionary should be for it to work in the function. The function goes like this:

```
...

for data in form.cleaned_data["f"]:
    data_point = models.DataPoint.objects.get(id=data["id"])
```

I thought that the dictionary should be in the following format:

```
form.cleaned_data = {'f': {"id": "1234"}}
```

but I keep getting this error when running the test:

```
    id=data["id"]
E   TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Do `print(data); print(type(data))`. I suspect your `data` variable is a string not a dictionary that has the key `id`.

Comment: `data` **is** `"id"`.

Comment: `form.cleaned_data["flows"]` is a dictionary, namely, `{"id": "1234"}`. If you iterate through a dictionary, it iterates through it's keys. I'd wager `cleaned_data["flows"]` is a list of dictionaries, something like `{'flows': [{"id": "1234"}, {"id", "5678"}]}`

Comment: Do `for data in form.cleaned_data["flows"].items()` instead of `for data in form.cleaned_data["flows"]`

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over a dict, you get their key and not their value. Which means to access the value we have to use variable[key], you were trying, to access the key, like a dict, since the key is a string, python was assuming you tried to access a char of the string, but this can only be done with an int.

```
for key in form.cleaned_data["flows"]:
    data_point = property.MeterPoint.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data["flows"][key]["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what framework you are using but what I can say is that if

```
form.cleaned_data["flow"]
```

is the dictionary you defined as

```
{"id": "1234"}
```

then your data variable has a type of `str` (string).
Because looping over a dictionary is looping over the keys of dictionary.
If you want to loop over values you can use `.values()` method e.g.

```
for data in my_dict.values():
    print(data)
```

If you use `.values()` then your data would be of type `str` (string) and have a value of `"1234"`.

Moreover you can loop over a tuple of (pair of) key-value items.
for this purpose you can use `.items()` method. e.g.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

- Note about tuple unpacking:
  If you have a tuple such as `t = (1, 2, 3)` you can assign it into three
  variables as `a, b, c = t`. With this you have `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3`.

Some note about the error:
The error you are faceing is because type of `data` is probably `str` and for accessing index of a string you should pass an `int` (integer) value not a string.